# Planes and polytopes in n dimensional space

Tags: reference-request

Imagine there are K vectors in n-dimensional space. I would like to:

- validate whether they can correspond to K+1 planes enclosing a volume (is that called a polytope?)
- validate whether a given further vector is completely inside this polytope, or not.

This should be known math problems I assume, but I do not know the names of corresponding solution approaches/terms.

Comment: A re-formulation of your issue: "does the **convex hull** of these $K$ points have $K$ vertices (all points participate to the convex hull) ? "

Comment: Are you sure that $K$ points define $K+1$ planes ? Take the case of the tretahedron (also called simplex) in $\mathbb{R}^3$ : its 4 vertices define 4 planes; not 5. Besides, you don't say if $K<n, K=n, K>n$...

Comment: Any comment to my comments ?

Comment: thank you - I think the term "convex hull" nails it.

Comment: You haven't answered my question about the tetrahedron (pyramid with triangular base) which has $K=4$ vertices and $K=4$ limiting planes

Comment: right, then it's not K+1